# Как перевести список чисел в число?

Tags: python, строки, list, числа

Дан список: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]`
Необходимый вывод: `1234567890`

Comment: С помощью цикла и умножения на 10

Comment: Это конечно замечательно, что понабежала куча народу, готовая набить себе репу на легком вопросе. Только никто не заметил, что вопрос относится к категории "сделайте за меня мое задание" и является нежелательным для данного ресурса. Здесь не площадка по решению заданий. 
Хотите, что бы кто-то за вас сделал вашу работу - 
обращайтесь к фрилансерам.

Comment: @cauf Никто тут не ясновидящий, чтоб сказать — домашка это или нет. Зато очевидно, что это достачно атомарный вопрос, чтоб быть 
онтопиком. Плюс такая задача вполне возникает на практике, так что очень неплохо пополнить нашу базу знаний.

Answer (score 3):

Можно преобразовать список чисел в список строк с помощью [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)/[`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str), а затем подать объект на вход [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) через пустую строку, а затем, по необходимости, снова перевести в число:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
int(''.join(map(str, lst)))
```

Comment: вот, блин — хотел именно такой ответ написать. ;)

Comment: а я его, вообще говоря, случайно написал — очитался в вопросе — думал OP'у строка на выходе нужна... а когда перечитал хотел сначала на вариант с `reduce` заменить, но как-то стало лень т.к. ссылки уже накидал... да и вопрос в такой формулировке неуниверсальным показался... так что просто добавил `int` и оставил как-есть... вот такой бессмысленный анекдот...

Comment: Я б только добавил, что если в списке не только числа, то надо сделать так: `int(''.join(str(i) for i in lst if str(i).isdigit())))`

Comment: без `map` оно как-то не функционально выглядит... эстетические чувства страдают...

Comment: Ну и что? ;) Зато pythonic.

Comment: Бросим функциональщину с Парохода Современности!

Answer (score 2):

Быстрее:

```py
from functools import reduce

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
result = reduce(lambda x, y: x * 10 + y, a)
```

Проще:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
result = int(''.join(map(str, a)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```
print(str(x)[1:-1].replace(", ", ""))
```

`str(x)` - превращаем в строку
`[1:-1]` - убираем скобки
`replace(", ", "")` - убираем все `", "`

Answer (score 2):

решения без привлечения внешних библиотек:

через сумму

способ 1:

```
res = sum(10**obj[0] * obj[1] for obj in enumerate(reversed(arr)))
```

способ 2:

```
res = sum(10**obj[0] * obj[1] for obj in enumerate(arr[::-1]))
```

способ 3:

```
res = sum(10**(len(arr) - obj[0] - 1) * obj[1] for obj in enumerate(arr))
```

через преобразование строк:

способ 4:

```
res = int(''.join(map(str, arr)))
```

способ 5:

```
res = int(''.join(str(i) for i in arr))
```

через решение в лоб (по сути та же сумма, но без функции `sum`)

способ 6:

```
res = 0
for i in arr:
  res = res * 10 + i
```

извращённый способ по формированию строки без `join`:

способ 7:

```
res = int(str(arr).replace(' ', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(',', ''))
```

продолжаем извращения с микроскопом и гвоздями - предыдущий способ, но более совершенный:

способ 8:

```
res = int(str(arr).translate(str.maketrans('', '', ' ,[]')))
```